# If i change the backend of my website from php/wordpress to say, ruby, how will this affect my site? And also the seo of my site?

Tags: seo, wordpress

I'm planning to start a website on php/WordPress. It might get complicated fast due to the amount of categories and sub categories etc? Later on I would like to expand the site, but due to the rigid nature of wordpress I change the backend to ruby. How will this affect my site? How will this affect SEO?

Comment: Sorry but its unclear what your asking. It would depend on the backend effecting the frontend. Google or Bing does not care what CMS or software you use.

Answer (score 1):

If all the url pages are the same, or are properly redirected, and no 404 errors crop up, then there should be no SEO devaluation.
The only other issue might be with page speed.. if the new pages are loading faster or slower.